# Python pandas ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 48:03.3

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, azure-databricks, timedelta

In a notebook inside [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/what-is-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20is%20a%20data,Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20services%20platform.&text=For%20a%20big%20data%20pipeline,Event%20Hub%2C%20or%20IoT%20Hub.), the following code loads data from a `csv` file into `pandas dataframe`. The `OrderDate` column values look like the ones shown in image below. `print(data_df['OrderDate'])` prints the values all the way to the almost second last row. And in the next row I get the error shown below:

**Question**: What could be the cause of the error and how can we fix it?

**Sample of csv file OrderDate column values**:

[image]

> ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 48:03.3

**Output of print(data_df['OrderDate']) line** [Above error occurs at row 145207]:

```
0         48:03.3
1         25:25.8
2         05:19.4
3         35:16.9
4         56:40.6
           ...   
145204    40:22.4
145205    25:17.8
145206    25:19.7
Name: OrderDate, Length: 145207, dtype: object
```

**Error occurs at last line of the following code**:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myDataFile.csv', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer')

print(data_df['OrderDate'])
data_df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['OrderDate'])
```

Comment: Seems like hours of the 0-23 range can't be parsed because they're not part of a datetime. Maybe parse and transform the number of hours to an intermediate representation before transforming them into a datetime object?

Comment: btw. *the cause* of the error is that you try to parse to datetime, and the parser interprets e.g. `48:...` as 48 hours etc. - which does not exist on a 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

Your input seems to be a *duration*, not a *time*, as in date & time. Parse [to timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then add that to a reference date to get datetime dtype.
Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': ["40:22.4", "25:17.8", "25:19.7"]})

df['datetime'] = pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01") + pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['duration'])

df['datetime']
0   1900-01-01 00:40:22.400
1   1900-01-01 00:25:17.800
2   1900-01-01 00:25:19.700
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```